# How to convert a data frame to a "GTiff" format com cell-values

Tags: raster, r

I generated this model in R, I think it is a Data Frame file, how can I transform it to a format="GTiff"?

```
relevo.df$precipi <- predict(modelo,relevo.df)
print(relevo.df)
ggplot(relevo.df)+
  geom_raster(aes(x=lon,y=lat,fill=precipi))+
 ## geom_sf(data = mg,fill='NA')+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = tim.colors(10))+
  annotation_scale()+
  annotation_north_arrow(location='tl',
                         style = north_arrow_orienteering())+
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL,fill='[mm]',title = 'Modelo de precipitaçao municipio do Sobral')+
  theme_minimal()
```

spg<-relevo.df
coordinates(spg)<- ~lon+lat
gridded(spg)<-TRUE
rasterDF<-raster(spg)
rasterDF

writeRaster(rasterDF, filename="precipitacion", datatype="INT1U", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)

How can I export the same raster but with the values of my field of interest?

---

I managed to generate the raster, I only need the information about the values of the raster.

Comment: See this post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627344/how-to-create-a-raster-from-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to convert the data frame to raster, however the raster does not have the field of my interest 'pluiviosity'.

How can I export the same raster but with the cell-values of my field of interest.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the first three columns of your data frame are longitude (x), latitude (y), and 'pluviosity', respectively.

Comment: spg<-relevo.df
coordinates(spg)<- ~lon+lat+precipi

I get this error

Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ~lon + lat + precipi) : 
  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set

Comment: get rid of that line